# How to implement Ruby On Rails Delayed Job in Azure

Tags: azure, delayed-job, azure-sdk-for-ruby

I have a ruby app hosted in azure (app service). And i wanted to implement Delayed Job in that. Can anyone help me how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

How is your app deployed ? Are you using Docker in which case you should be able to deploy a web and a worker container with docker-compose.

Otherwise, you should check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs#azure-web-apps-and-webjobs

Comment: Your post in not an answer, rather add questions in the comment section.